# When did the Sateré-Mawé people start using Bullet Ants in their initiation rites?

Tags: native-americans, south-america

I just read the very short wiki article on the [Satere-Mawe people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maw%C3%A9_people) from South America. They have an initiation rite where a bunch of [Bullet Ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraponera_clavata) sting someone for 10 minutes, and not only that, but to repeat this a total of 20 times over the years.

I would like to know when that practice started. Can it be dated through oral history? Were there perhaps other tribes in the past that did the same thing? At the very least, I'm hoping for the earliest mention of it in a written account.

I tried to google this but mostly got pop culture websites with no history. Maybe someone knows a search technique that can find this.

**Edit:** I got a tumbleweed badge for this question. I'll take it as a good sign to open a bounty.